# Is there any expression or a single verb for "making someone expect something"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there any expression or a single verb for "making someone expect something"?

For example, the title "A Walk Among the Tombstones" **made me expect** a horror movie.

Comment: ...maybe you have never done a _genealogy_. It's kinda peaceful.

Answer (score 4):

You could say that the title "**suggested**," "**foreshadowed**," or "**evoked**" a horror movie.

Comment: +1 for *"A Walk Among the Tombstones" suggests a horror movie*

Answer (score 1):

Something else that is close is **implied**:

> "A Walk Among the Tombstones" **implied** a horror movie.

Also **implicit**

> Suggested though not directly expressed.
>
> <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/implicit)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

**I anticipated** “A Walk Among the Tombstones" to be horror movie.